# Why doesn't add event be triggered when Collection fetch successfully?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var documents = new Backbone.Collection();  
documents.url = "/documents";  

documents.bind("add", function(doc){
    console.log(doc);
});  

documents.fetch();
```

Why doesn't the `add` event triggered when the `fetch` function gets the array of models successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What documentation says:

> When the model data returns from the server, the collection will reset ...
>   If you'd like to add the incoming models to the current collection, instead of replacing the collection's contents, pass {add: true} as an option to fetch.

So the answer to your question: call fetch like this

```
documents.fetch({add: true});
```

And it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event `add` is fired after you add elements to an already populated Collection.

In this specific case you can listen to the `reset` event instead of `add`. Also remember to verify that your collection it's getting data at all.